# InfluxDB get all measurements that have entry at specific time

Tags: influxdb

I use InfluxDB OSS, version 1.18.

I have a database (*d1*) with a lot of measurements, for the sake of simplicity let's name them *m1* to *m20000* (real names are different and regex cannot be made to match them all). There is another measurement named *sent* too. They all have a single field inside named value. Only about (random) 100-500 of them are being written at a moment in time, with the same timestamp. Each time a write occurs, sent measurement is also written to. Example:

- at 17:00:00, m123 to m567 are being populated with various values, sent is populated with 0
- at 17:00:15, m2345 to m2890 are being populated with various values, sent is populated with 0
- at 17:00:15, m1234 to m1876 are being populated with various values, sent is populated with 1

At a later point in time, I get all timestamps where sent is 0. Then I loop through the timestamps to get the values for the measurements in order to send them.

I need a quick and efficient way of getting the measurements that have entries at a given timestamp. Something like `SHOW MEASUREMENTS WHERE time = timestamp`

One way it will work is to make requests for all measurements individually for every timestamp, but that will cause A LOT of requests to influxdb.

Other option is to write the unsent values for measurements (writes where sent would be 0) to a separate database, then I'll only need to query that database and upon sending them, I'll delete the entries from that database.